# Updating a variable in a rhtml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a helper method to create rows by passing the number of rows as arguement
I want to update the argument "i" passed to the helper using a javascript.
How do I go about doing this? I tried using this script at the bottom.
can someone tell me a better way to go about this? 
Thank you so much

### Helper Method

```
    def injection_form(i)
    n=0
    if i.blank?
        i = 1 
    end
    table = '<tr>'
    until (n == i) do 
        table <<'<td> '
        table <<    "#{text_field_tag "injection_#{i}[antigen_number]",{}, :size => 3}"
        table <<'</td>'
        table <<'<td>'
        table <<    "#{ text_field_tag "injection_#{i}[animal_number]", {}, :size => 4}"
        table <<'</td>'
        table <<'</tr>'
        table <<'<tr>'
        n += 1
    end
    table << '</tr>'
    return table
end
```

### View

```
 <table class='animal-events'>
    <tr>
        <th> Antigen Number </th>
        <th> Animal Number </th>
        <td><button onclick="addRow(i);"> + </button></td>
    </tr>
   <% form_tag "recombinant_antibody/add_injections" do %>      
          <%= injection_form(i) %>
              <%=submit_tag "make"%>
  </table>
   <%end%>
```

### Script

```
    <script>
      function addRow(number) {         
           $('form').replaceChild('<%= injection_form('+number.toString()+')') 
        }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work the way you think it does. Your Ruby helper runs as the page loads and renders into the resulting HTML file that it sends to the browser. By the time your Javascript runs on the browser, <%= %> tags no longer have any meaning.

In order to do what you want to do the way you want to do it your Javascript will have to generate the exact HTML you want and insert that into the DOM. So you would have something like this:

```
<script>
  function addRow(number) {
    var nameTag = 'injection_' + number;
    var html = '<tr><td><input id="' + nameTag + '[antigen_number]" name="' + nameTag + '[antigen_number]" size="3" type="text" value="" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input id="' + nameTag + '[animal_number]" name="' + nameTag + '[animal_number]" size="4" type="text" value="" /></td>';
    html += '</td></tr>'
    $('form').append(html);
  }
</script>
```

I'm not sure if that will generate the exact HTML you need -- you should inspect the elements already in your form for that -- but that's the basic idea.

Comment: so I cannot reuse the helper method in anyway?

Comment: what you could do is move your form into a partial, create an action on your controller that renders that partial, and then call that action with $.ajax and insert the result into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is one more way to do it oldschool.
I ended up using this.
If anyone knows how to use the helper method in the js please post.

```
    function addRow(number){

var table = document.getElementById('test');

var nameTag = 'injection_' + number;

var ag_cell = document.createElement("td");

var animal_cell = document.createElement("td");

var ag_input = document.createElement("input");
    ag_input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    ag_input.setAttribute("id", nameTag + '_antigen_number' );
    ag_input.setAttribute("value", "");
    ag_input.setAttribute("name", nameTag + '[antigen_number]');
    ag_input.setAttribute("size", 3);
var animal_input = document.createElement("input");
    animal_input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    animal_input.setAttribute("id", nameTag + '_animal_number' );
    animal_input.setAttribute("value", "");
    animal_input.setAttribute("name", nameTag + '[animal_number]');
    animal_input.setAttribute("size", 4);
var ag_form = ag_cell.appendChild(ag_input);    

var animal_form = animal_cell.appendChild(animal_input);

var row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.appendChild(ag_cell).appendChild(ag_form);
    row.appendChild(animal_cell).appendChild(animal_form);
    table.appendChild(row);
   };
```